# Python3 Sending Email with Smtplib [Yandex]

Tags: python, python-3.x, smtp, smtp-auth

I'm trying to send emails using yandex but my function doesn't work. It's just waiting forever there is no error either. Here is my function :

```
def send_emails(title,msg):
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.yandex.com.tr:465')
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.login(yandex_mail,yandex_pass)
    message = 'Subject: {}\n\n{}'.format(title,msg)
    server.sendmail(yandex_mail,send_to_email,message)
    server.quit()
    print('E-mails successfully sent!')

send_emails('Test Mail', 'Yes its a test mail!')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i think your problem is here:

```
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.yandex.com.tr:465')
```

you need to use [smtplib.SMTP_SSL](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP_SSL) because connection is security with `SSL` [docs](https://yandex.com/support/mail/mail-clients.html#imap), also `smtplib.SMTP_SSL` get many params, first is `host` and second is `port` and other params, but you need now only this two, you need to give `host` and `port` separately, try this

```
def send_emails(title,msg):
    server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.yandex.com.tr', 465)
    ...
```

Comment: Nothing changed it's still waiting forever.

Comment: but without `tr` ? `smtp.yandex.com` only

Comment: I tried both same behaviour. I found old question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39516200/python-get-gmail-server-with-smtplib-never-ends - but there is no solution either

Comment: try to put another `server.ehlo()` after `server.starttls()`

Comment: It's never reaching to `server.ehlo` or `server.starttls`. I put `print('1')`, `print('2')` etc after each code. it didn't print anything after `server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.yandex.com',465)` so it's stucking on this line. I pinged yandex.com too there is no problem with connection

Comment: i update my answer try to use `smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.yandex.com', 465)`, important `smtplib.SMTP_SSL()` if i print out any thing after this it works

Comment: Thanks! It's worked with `SMTP_SSL` but i guess yandex doesn't support `starttls` so i removed that part too for make it work. Thanks again!